# Room database scroll to a particular position using Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am using Room data base to fetch the data from the data base. Recyclerview I want to scroll to a particular position in recyclerview.

I have already tried list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)

StationListRepository stationListRepositoryOnlyActive = new StationListRepository(getApplicationContext());
        stationListRepositoryOnlyActive.getActiveStationList().observe(this, new Observer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List OnlyActivestations) {
                Log.d("OnlyActivestations", "" + OnlyActivestations.size());
                assert OnlyActivestations != null;
                if (OnlyActivestations.size() > 0 || FinalList.size() > 0) {
                    if (FinalList != null && FinalList.size() > 0) {
                        OnlyActivestations = sortList(OnlyActivestations);
                        FinalList.addAll(OnlyActivestations);

```
                } else {
                    OnlyActivestations = sortList(OnlyActivestations);
                    FinalList = OnlyActivestations;
                }
                Log.d("FinalListSizeActive",""+FinalList.size());
                detailsAdapter = new db_stationListAdapter(context, FinalList);
                //recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                staggeredGridLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(10);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);
                detailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // stopLoading();
                        stopAnimation();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I except the recycler view to auto scroll to the position 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the code below after you set the data to the adapter

recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);

or

You can add **OnLayoutChangeListener** to your RecyclerView.

recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener(){

```
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int 
             right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, 
                         int oldBottom) {

            if (bottom < oldBottom) {

                   recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);


                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your second solution worked for me, I am really thankful to you.